# VBA Change Column Header Name and Reorganize

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Im in charge of onboarding employees into our SSO platform. I get a CSV file with employee information in the format of:
[image: Excel screenshot of potential information for provided CSV]
Ive already trimmed the data by deleting empty rows, and terminated employees. (As this is a census of all employees since the start of the company.)

I have never used macros before, but this is becoming a routine task with 300+ employees and is becoming very time consuming. What Im looking to have accomplished now is rename each of the columns and organize them in a specific order. 
First: Delete column Status (active/Terminated) and column Current Employment Start Date and Preferred Name. Then rename the columns as such:

```
Employee ID = employeeNumber

First Name = firstName

Last Name = lastName

Middle Name = middleName

Work Email = login

Title = title

Personal Email = secondEmail

Phone = mobilePhone

Employment = userType

Department = department

Manager (name) = manager
```

Once those columns are renamed I'd want it to be organized, and blank columns with specific column headers to be entered in between. There are 3 columns that are all based off of the same information in the final sheet: login, email, and federation_id. I would want the final list in this order:

> login/firstName/lastName/middleName/honorificPrefix/honorificSuffix/email/title/displayName/nickName/profileUrl/secondEmail/mobilePhone/primaryPhone/streetAddress/city/state/zipCode/countryCode/postalAddress/preferredLanguage/locale/timezone/userType/employeeNumber/costCenter/organization/division/department/managerId/manager/adm_email/adm_username/tcheckAccess/Federation_ID/sshUserName/houstonEmail/activeDate

Here is my code that I've written so far:

```
Option Explicit

Sub census_it()

'declare variables
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim new_column_order As Variant, new_index As Integer

'set variables
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test")

'clear all filters just incase
ws.ShowAllData

'select range, first column, show all blank,,,, diable alerts,,, delete all visible cells in range,,, enable alerts,,, clear filter
ws.Range("A:O").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=""
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ws.Range("A2:O9999").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
On Error Resume Next
ws.ShowAllData
On Error GoTo 0

'select range, first column, show all blank,,,, diable alerts,,, delete all visible cells in range,,, enable alerts,,, clear filter
ws.Range("A:O").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="Terminated"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ws.Range("A2:O9999").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
On Error Resume Next
ws.ShowAllData
On Error GoTo 0

ws.Range("A:O").AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:=">1/28/2020"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ws.Range("A2:O9999").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
On Error Resume Next
ws.ShowAllData
On Error GoTo 0

'everything below here doesnt work (and this is for reorganizing the data

iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Long’Constant values
data_sheet1 = InputBox(“Specify the name of the Sheet that needs to be reorganised:”) ‘Create Input Box to ask the user which sheet needs to be reorganised
target_sheet = “Final Report” ‘Specify the sheet to store the results
iRow = Sheets(data_sheet1).UsedRange.Rows.Count ‘Determine how many rows are in use’Create a new sheet to store the results
Worksheets.Add.Name = “Final Report”
‘Start organizing columns
For iCol = 1 To Sheets(data_sheet1).UsedRange.Columns.Count

‘Sets the TargetCol to zero in order to prevent overwriting existing targetcolumns
TargetCol = 0

‘Read the header of the original sheet to determine the column order
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = “First Name” Then TargetCol = 1
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = “Middle Name” Then TargetCol = 2
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = “Last Name” Then TargetCol = 3
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = “Date of Birth” Then TargetCol = 4
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = “Phone Number” Then TargetCol = 5
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = “Address” Then TargetCol = 6
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = “City” Then TargetCol = 7
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = “State” Then TargetCol = 8
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = “Postal (ZIP) Code” Then TargetCol = 9
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = “Country” Then TargetCol = 10

‘If a TargetColumn was determined (based upon the header information) then copy the column to the right spot
If TargetCol <> 0 Then
‘Select the column and copy it
Sheets(data_sheet1).Range(Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol), Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(iRow, iCol)).Copy Destination:=Sheets(target_sheet).Cells(1, TargetCol)
End If

End Sub
```

I got the code from http://www.winko-erades.nl/rearrange-columns-in-excel-using-vba/ . But i think the issue is the file is already in CSV format, and does have any tables in it. And this code is for tables on a worksheet, not just a worksheet. Also, I don't know how to enter in blank columns of data with specific headers.
Any help or guidance of pointing me in the right direction to accomplish what i want would be well appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: What version of Excel? Power Query might be a better option here.

Comment: Im on version 16.33 but for Apple, Mac laptop.